# Switching profiles based on networks availability

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, automation, profiles

While there are plenty of apps to switch profiles based on various triggers (time, position, ...), [Llama](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kebab.Llama&hl=en) being an excellent one for instance -- I did not manage to find any which would from time to time switch a network device on (Wifi, Bluetooth) and check whether a previously configured network is available, then connect if it is available. Should the network not be available, or not be available anymore, the device would be switched off. Until the next check.

This would be extremely useful for someone who is neither very much "time organized" (ie. I do not know what I will be doing a Tuesday at 10:00), nor "place organized" (I spend some time in the neighborhood of my WiFi access point, without the access point being close enough to be connected to, but close enough for cell/GPS based location to think I am in its direct vicinity).

Would someone know of such an application (or a combo - one for WiFi, one for Bluetooth)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual: try with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm). *Tasker* can react on "network near" (check for WiFi SSID), you also can check signal levels and react depending on that. This way you could not even check whether a certain WiFi network is *in reach*, but also how strong its signal is -- which might prove helpful e.g. in an office building with multiple WiFi networks to determine which room you are in.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Would it be able to run the scenario I described (switch on WiFi / Bluetooth - check for network presence, stay on if the network is there, otherwise switch off? And run this in a reasonable cycle so that the device (WiFi / Bluetooth) is switched off when the network disappears?) - it looks so from the description in Google Play

Comment: I'm pretty sure of it, yes. You might want to check for details on the [Tasker homepage](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/), especially in the [Tasker UserGuide](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/).